# retrive the data from database code add the custom function from the plugin file

Tags: php, css, database, wordpress

```
 $donorQuery->joinRaw("JOIN ({$donationQuery->getSQL()}) AS sub ON donors.id = sub.donorId");

     if ($this->shouldIncludeAddress()) {
        $donorQuery->attachMeta('give_donormeta',
            'donors.ID',
            'donor_id',
            ['give_phone', 'give_phone'],//added code
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_line1_0', 'address_line1'],
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_line2_0', 'address_line2'],
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_city_0',  'address_city'],
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_state_0', 'address_state'],
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_zip_0',   'address_zip'],
            ['_give_donor_address_billing_country_0', 'address_country'],
            
            
        );
    }
```

how to add a phone no query in this function without disturbing it  to add a custom function it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `_give_donor_phone` is the meta key for the phone, try this

```
 $donorQuery->attachMeta('give_donormeta',
        'donors.ID',
        'donor_id',
        ['_give_donor_phone', 'phone_number'], 
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_line1_0', 'address_line1'],
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_line2_0', 'address_line2'],
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_city_0',  'address_city'],
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_state_0', 'address_state'],
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_zip_0',   'address_zip'],
        ['_give_donor_address_billing_country_0', 'address_country']
        // ... Other existing fields ...
    );
```

Comment: yeah that is i know but same thing i do in other  place custom functions.php